# Expected value of functions of random variables

Tags: probability

Is the following correct

$$ \mathbb{P}[ X >(Y+Z)] = E_{Y}\left(\mathbb{P}[ X >(y+Z)]_{y=Y}\right)$$

Comment: I've edited your question, pls confirm if it's what you want to ask

Comment: how do I confirm

Comment: Just tell me if my edition is ok for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
 \mathbb{P}\left( X >(Y+Z)\right) &= \int_{}f_y(y)\mathbb{P}\left( X >(y+Z)\right) \\&= E_{Y}\left(\mathbb{P}[ X >(y+Z)]\right)
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

If $Z=0$ and $Y=X$, the LHS is $0$, but the RHS can be strictly positive.

So you need some assumptions, such as $Y$ is independent of $X$ and $Z$

Comment: How could the RHS be strictly positive? If $Z=0$ and $X=Y$ then given $Y=y$ you will have $X=y$ and $y+Z=y$ so  $\mathbb{P}[ X \gt (y+Z)]_{y=Y}=0$ and $E_Y[0]=0$

Comment: thats true thanks Henry

Comment: @Henry We take the function $f(y) = P(X >y)$, then we evaluate $E_Y(f(Y))$

Comment: @jennifer Please see my reply to Henry